# Use json_encode() with a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following code which allows me to echo my product categories in wordpress withing a select box:

```
 $arguments = array(
            'number'     => $number,
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            'order'      => $order,
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
            'include'    => $ids
 );

 $product_cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $arguments );

 foreach ( $product_cats as $cat ) :
  echo '<option value="' . $cat->term_id . '">' . $cat->name . '</option>';
 endforeach;
```

I am trying to use the returned values from my foreach loop within the  json_encode() so that I can use the categories in my javascript code.

But I cannot figure out a way to do it, can anyone provide any guidance?

If i use

```
<?php echo json_encode($product_cats); ?>
```

it does not work

Comment: json_encode($cat); inside the foreach?

Comment: Why do you want to use `json_encode() ` ?

Comment: turn off echo '<option value="' . $cat->term_id . '">' . $cat->name . '</option>';. Only use echo json_encode($product_cats);  outside loop. Your whole output should be one json string

Comment: Hello, Because, In my javascript, I am adding a button which allows the user to add an extra input box (if needed) including the category selection box when clicked

Answer (score 1):

try in javascript tag;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCatJSON = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($product_cats); ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: If this is the answer then why he needs JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside a javascript tag. Remember the code should be outside PHP tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$cat_array = json_encode($product_cats);
echo "var javasc_cat_array = ". $cat_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggested try to put it in the script tags like this:

```
<script>
    var cat = <?=json_encode($product_cats); ?>
</script>
```

And then you can use cat as a javascript object.

P.S. : Don't forget to use this **BEFORE** you do the foreach loop as it "empties" the array.